# Retornar a última entrada de diferentes objetos Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Supondo que eu tenha duas tabelas:
**Carro** contendo: placa, ano, ect.. **Evento** contendo: carro, lat, long, data, hora, etc..
Como eu poderia retornar apenas a última entrada de cada carro na tabela evento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria algo como:

```
SELECT C.*, E.*
FROM CARRO C
JOIN EVENTO E
    JOIN E.CARRO_ID = C.ID
    AND E.DATA_HORA = (
            SELECT MAX(DATA_DATA) 
            FROM EVENTO E2
            WHERE E2.CARRO_ID = E.CARRO_ID
        )
```

A explicação:

1. O *join* seleciona o carro e todos os seus eventos através da expressão `E.CARRO_ID = C.ID`
2. O *subselect* apenas a data mais recente de todos os eventos para aquele carro
3. Dessa forma, a segunda cláusula da junção faz com que a query só retorne o evento cuja data seja a maior

Note que o campo  deve ter a data e a hora e não devem ter dois eventos no mesmo instante, caso contrário pode selecionar dois eventos. Existe uma forma de contornar isso, mas seria quase uma gambiarra, é mais razoável não ter dois eventos no mesmo momento.

Comment: Essa solução me foi útil, obrigado utluiz!!

Answer (score 0):

Se você está querendo apenas consultar os dados, você pode usar a seguinte query...

```
SELECT DISTINCT evt.carro, evt.lat, evt.long, evt.data, evt.hora, etc...
FROM Evento evt, Carro car
WHERE evt.carro = car.placa AND (evt.carro, evt.data) IN
                                            (SELECT carro, data
                                             FROM Evento, Carro
                                             WHERE data >= ALL AND Evento.carro = Carro.placa)
```

O `DISTINCT` é usado para evitar repetições.

Comment: Isso vai listar todos os eventos, não somente o último em relação ao carro.

Answer (score 0):

`distinct on` retornará apenas uma linha para cada `carro_id`. Na cláusula `order by` decide-se qual delas.

```
select distinct on (carro_id) *
from
    carro
    inner join
    evento using(carro_id)
order by carro_id, data desc, hora desc
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT